# Tensor product of adjoint operators

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tensor-products

I'm working over $G = SU(2)$. $g$ represents an element of $G$, and $E,F$ are elements of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. Since these are $2\times 2$ matrices, the natural tensor product space is $4\times4$.

I have to do a computation like $(Ad_g \otimes Ad_g)(E\otimes F - F\otimes E)$, where $Ad_g E = gEg^{-1}$. I know I can compute $Ad_g E = E'$, $Ad_g F = F'$, and so $(Ad_g \otimes Ad_g)(E\otimes F - F\otimes E) = E'\otimes F' - F'\otimes E'$. However, $E\otimes F - F\otimes E$ is a very simple element, and I wish to directly somehow directly apply $Ad_g\otimes Ad_g$ to it to the $4\times4$ matrix representation of $E\otimes F - F\otimes E$.

Comment: I don't understand, it sounds like you're asking how to apply ${\rm Ad}_g\otimes {\rm Ad}_g$ to $e\otimes f-f\otimes e$ but it also sounds like you *already know* how to do that. So what's your question?

Comment: @runway44 my point is that i want to use the already calculated value of ExF-FxE (excuse the unformatted response), rather than applying Ad_g to E and F separately, computing tensor products, and so on.

Comment: I assume $E$ and $F$ are $2\times 2$ complex matrices, and $E\otimes F$ is the Kronecker product? Then you can just use ${\rm Ad}_g\otimes{\rm Ad}_g={\rm Ad}_{g\otimes g}$, which follows from the interchange law $(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)=(AC)\otimes(BD)$.

Comment: @runway44 okay, i will check and see if this works